# Маршрутизация, добавление маршрута

Tags: сеть, ip, маршрутизация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

какой маршрут прописать, чтобы из подсетки 192.168.1.* была доступна подсетка 192.168.21.26?

Comment: Сервер должен обеспечивать маршрутизацию из одной сети в другую и обратно. Если у него не установлено никаких ограничений - то дополнительных настроек по идее не требуется. Если и возникнет проблема - так только на той стороне, у удалённых узлов из сети 192.168.21.0/24, у них может не быть маршрута в 192.168.1.0/24, а 192.168.21.26 у них не def.gw.

Comment: это понятно, отолько 192.168.21. не видна остальное все видно

Comment: Доступен ли с 192.168.1.100 узел 192.168.21.26? Если нет - что показывает пинг (dest. unreacheable или timeout)?

Comment: пингую со свитча 192.168.1.1 (удалено) 192.168.21.26 -  реакция - "is dead", пакеты идут на шлюз 192.168.1.2 (физический интерфейс eth4) они соединены со свитчем волокном, а дальше затык

Comment: А что за туннель ? 10.8.0.5 это удаленный конец туннеля ? Пингуется ли этот адрес с сервера. Если да, то на сервере должна быть маршрутизация вроде `route add 192.168.21.26 gw 10.8.0.5`

Comment: 10.8.0.6 пингуется а 10.8.0.5 - нет. 10.8.0.5 это конец тунеля выход на машину где висит интерфейс с адресом 192.168.21.26. А на "сервере" прописано 192.168.21.0 -> 10.8.0.5

Comment: это было про пинг со свитча (192.168.1.1) а с самого сервера все пингуется и доступно

Comment: вот ту строчку что я написал сделайте на сервер, если ее еще нет

Comment: *пингую со свитча 192.168.1.1 (удалено) 192.168.21.26 - реакция - "is dead"* Этого мало - необходимо знать, как именно dead. *10.8.0.6 пингуется а 10.8.0.5 - нет.* А узел 10.8.0.5 знает маршрут к 192.168.1.0/24?

Comment: Кстати да, надо что бы на той стороне был обратный маршрут ... Вообще запускайте `tcpdump -n -i tun0 icmp` и пингуйте ту сторону. гон вам покажет все пакеты которые проходят. соответственно должны быть и исходящие и входящие. Если никаких нет, смотрите так же на интерфейсе в сторону того кто посылает, что бы понять добрались ли пакеты до сервера

Comment: запустил tcpdump пингую со свитча 21.26 - icmp пакеты проходят, пингую 10.8.05 - пакеты проходят. В чем тогда проблема? почему свитч выдает is dead и телефон не может найти соответственно провайдера

Comment: пакеты проходят и туда и обратно ? нормальный ping выглядит так: туда `IP 10.0.64.2 > 10.0.64.25: ICMP echo request ...` и обратно `IP 10.0.64.25 > 10.0.64.2: ICMP echo reply ...`  Если да, то посмотрите то же самое на eth4

Comment: обратно пакеты на 192.168.1.1 от 192.168.21.26 не идут, что означает, что на "той" стороне что надо сделать/добавить?

Comment: Ну тут 2 варианта, либо на той стороне вообще закрыт ping, фаерволом например. Или нет маршрутизации. соответственно там надо добавить маршрут на подсеть 192.168.1.0/24 через 10.8.0.6